# Random error: #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql

Ive had mysql up and running for month now. I was using it yesterday, and today I go to login via phpmyadmin and the command line and I suddenly can't. Its as if someone changed my password overnight or something. Im trying to login using the root user. What do I do?

**Edit**

This is mysql just running on my local laptop for development. The only account on it is the root account, and no caps lock is not on.

Comment: I updated it for you with more info. Thanks.

Comment: You should post the error message you're getting.

Comment: Do you get this error all the time? Can you login into MySQL shell with the username/password you got?

Comment: There's a kind of [tutorial](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/) that might be helpful to you.

Comment: @raina77ow This is the first time I have ever encountered the error, and no i can't login via the shell either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) raina77ow provided and followed the instructions to reset my password and it works now.

Scrolling down to section ***C.5.4.1.3. Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions*** was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html says this five step process will work, **try at your own risk obviously**. This source also has essentially the same steps. This likely won't work on windows, but something similar should http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442

Stop mysql service using `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Start mysql without password using `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

Connect to the server using `mysql -u root`

Change the root password:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Stop the Server: `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Start the Server: `/etc/init.d/mysql start`

Test: `mysql -u root -p`