# Configure phpMyAdmin with username and password not allows to login

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, lamp

I'm using phpMyAdmin on CentOS v6. Configured it to authentication type: cookie, I set username and password. (in  /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php)

When I browse to http ://my-server/phpMyAdmin/ I get a web login form, I entered the username and password that I worte in the configuration file **but it tells**:

> #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I looked after the following guide: http://ifzenelse.net/en/install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a conflict: the phpMyAdmin configuration that says to not allow login without a password (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']= FALSE;`), but my mysql user (root) had no password so I couldn't login!

So as mentioned in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357561/error-1045-cannot-log-in-to-mysql-server-phpmyadmin) I had to set password to the root user by:

```
# mysqladmin -u root password your-password
```

Then restart servers and login again

Answer (score 0):

Following steps would help you to login phpmyadmin without password.

1. Search for config.inc.php in phpmyadmin package. If not found, rename config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php
2. Search $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false; and make it $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Now you would be able to login successfully.