# Error#2002 on clicking PHP my admin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I tried to access  phpmyadmin  then it directed me to a page showing message  "access denied".Help me I am unable to get away from it. I am using windows8.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have started mysql server

Comment: Check if mysql is running or not.

Comment: check your xampp service, is mysql service started or not. The error message means phpmyadmin cannot communicate with mysql server

Comment: will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error # 1045 - Cannot Log in to MySQL server -> phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357561/error-1045-cannot-log-in-to-mysql-server-phpmyadmin)